# How to add rule in NGINX to remove date part from url

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

Need help with NGINX rewrite, I have a WordPress blog, which converted into Asp.net Core. It hosted on linux machine, webserver as NGINX.

Previously url were https://example.com/2015/06/hello-world, now I want to remove date part from url and redirect it to https://example.com/hello-world

Below in my nginx cofig file

**proxy.conf**

```
server {
    server_name codepedia.info;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://blogmenia;
    }


    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/codepedia.info/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/codepedia.info/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
server {
    if ($host = codepedia.info) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    server_name codepedia.info;
    listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prepend a rewrite rule to your first server block like this

```
location / {
    rewrite "/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/(.*)" /$3 permanent;
    proxy_pass http://blogmenia;
}
```

This rule will permanently remove the date from your url it will look like this `https://example.com/hello-world` and then it serves the proxy

**Note : you can update the regular expression in case of any date modifications in your url**